# Programmatically registering a component for destruction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

If we implement `OnDestroy` then Angular calls `ngOnDestroy` on the component when it is destroyed.

Is it possible to register a component for destruction with Angular programmatically from within the component itself (Withinout implementing `OnDestroy`?

The core use case I have in mind is modifying [ngx-take-until-destroyed](https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-take-until-destroy/blob/master/src/take-until-destroy.ts) such that the component would not have to implement `OnDestroy` in order to use the operator.

If the component implements `OnDestroy` then the operator could just proxy that method, but if it does not then the operator could sign the component up to have the `OnDestroy` method called by Angular.

This will eliminate a tiny bit of boilerplate.

Comment: you can always write a base class with this onDestroy logic and let component extend it

Comment: It could work.  It looks like it should be fairly safe to have the RxJS operator that that takes the component as an argument and wraps or adds a `ngOnDestroy` method should be easy to do though, and since unsubscribing from the RxJS Observable is the context, I think it will be a better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we implement `OnDestroy` then Angular calls `ngOnDestroy` on the
>   component when it is destroyed.

Given that `OnDestroy` is a TypeScript interface, it is not emitted into the compiled JavaScript output. Therefore, I expect that the mere existence of an `ngOnDestroy` function is enough for Angular to call it. It doesn't matter if `OnDestroy` is "implemented" on the class.

> Is it possible to register a component for destruction with Angular
>   programmatically from within the component itself (Withinout
>   implementing `OnDestroy`?

In Angular, components are not registered for destruction. You shouldn't look at `ngOnDestroy` as some form of garbage collection or a destructor. `ngOnDestroy` is called whenever a `Component` is removed from the DOM.

> The core use case I have in mind is modifying
>   [ngx-take-until-destroyed](https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-take-until-destroy/blob/master/src/take-until-destroy.ts)
>   such that the component would not have to implement `OnDestroy` in
>   order to use the operator.

The main unknown is when Angular checks for the existence of `ngOnDestroy`. If it checks right before calling it, then within ngx-take-until-destroyed simply removing the check if there is an `ngOnDestroy` function already present is enough.

If Angular checks at an earlier time, then I'm afraid having an empty `ngOnDestroy` is a necessity.

I tried to find the relevant destroy code within the Angular repository. But only found results for destroying providers. I think the easiest way to figure this out is simply by trying.

**EDIT**: based on the history of the project. It seems `ng build --prod` might also affect the outcome of this. Probably the extra check was added just for this.